# pox openflow - host_tracker not executing

Tags: openflow, sdn, pox

I am new to pox and I don't know how to run the components in pox. Currently I'm stuck with the host_tracker.py taken from https://github.com/CPqD/RouteFlow/blob/master/pox/pox/host_tracker/host_tracker.py

I've tried something like this:
`./debug-pox.py host_tracker`

And got the output as

`POX 0.3.0 (dart) / Copyright 2011-2014 James McCauley, et al.
DEBUG:core:POX 0.3.0 (dart) going up...
DEBUG:core:Running on CPython (2.7.6/Mar 22 2014 22:59:56)
DEBUG:core:Platform is Linux-3.13.0-53-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
DEBUG:core:host_tracker still waiting for: openflow
WARNING:core:Still waiting on 1 component(s)
INFO:core:POX 0.3.0 (dart) is up.`

Not sure what it means :( Kindly tell me how to run components in pox.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have mininet up and running you should use the host_tracker along with the openflow.discovery module. In addition you should load an example controller (stock component) included in your pox version. 
First load a sample mininet

```
sudo mn --controller remote
```

Then run pox like this

```
python pox.py forwarding.l2_pairs host_tracker openflow.discovery
```

When all is up and running in the terminal you launched mininet issue a

```
pingall
```

and monitor the terminal in which you run pox to observe host_tracker info

forwarding.l2_pairs is a sample controller (stock component) that will handle the network and flows modifications. host_tracker is the host tracker module and the openflow.discovery is the discovery module of pox.

To find more stock components go to https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki#POXWiki-StockComponents

To read more about host_tracker https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki#POXWiki-host_tracker

Comment: Thanks a lot! `openflow.discovery` is what I missed